# How do I configure subdomains with NGINX and DDNS

Tags: nginx, ddns

I have registered a ddns subdomain on No-IP:`example.ddns.net`
I configured No-IP to map to my router's IP which forwards the port to my NGINX web server. I want to have a separate web server that I hosted on `web1.example.ddns.net` which points to `/var/www/web1`. What I don't know is how to tell NGINX to point to `/var/www/web1` when called from `web1.example.ddns.net`. Can anyone give me a detailed explanation on how to configure my server?

Below is my configuration for `example.ddns.net` this config is located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` there is a link to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
       
        root /var/www/example.ddns.net;

        server_name example.ddns.net;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

Below is my configuration for `web1.example.ddns.net` this config is located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` there is a link to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
       
        root /var/www/web1.example.ddns.net;

        server_name web1.example.ddns.net;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

These are the only files I have changed. The following NGINX server is hosted on Ubuntu Server and I am accessing the server via ssh and accessing the webpage through a separate computer.
Can any one give some instructions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Check the error log. You cannot have both `server` blocks marked as the `default_server`. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to test the configuration file and ensure that both `server` blocks are present (but fix the `default_server` error first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

*The following answer is fairly basic. So please forgive me if I go over anything you already know. =)*

---

> I have registered a DDNS subdomain on No-IP: `example.ddns.net`. [...] I want to have a separate web server that I host on `web1.example.ddns.net` which points to `/var/www/web1`.

As a heads up, if you haven't done so already, you need to make ex. `web1.example.ddns.net` with No-IP and point it at your server. Otherwise, the server configuration will not matter, as no one will be able to contact the server via that address.

> What I don't know is how to tell NGINX to point to `/var/www/web1` when called from `web1.example.ddns.net`.

All you should really need are basic server blocks. Cribbing from the NGINX default examples:

*ex. example.ddns.net*

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.ddns.net;
        
        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /var/www/example.ddns.net;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        # error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
```

*ex. web1.example.ddns.net*

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  web1.example.ddns.net;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /var/www/web1;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        # error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
```

*Basic Instructions*

- For Ubuntu, you should place these server blocks under the appropriate `sites-available` directory (ex. `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`) as e.g. `example.ddns.net` and `web1.example.ddns.net`.
- Create the relevant symlinks to `sites-enabled` (ex. `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`) as e.g.:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.ddns.net /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
  sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/web1.example.ddns.net /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
  ```

  or by whatever method is recommended by your OS.
- Run `nginx -t` (as ex. `sudo nginx -t`) as suggested in the comments to ensure NGINX didn't encounter any syntax errors or other problems.
- Restart NGINX with ex. `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.

*Notes*

- The blocks above drop IPv6 (this likely shouldn't be necessary for testing).
- Neither of these examples use `default_server`.
- Each respective `root` entry is placed in a `location` block (i.e. the website root `/`).
- The second server block above uses `/var/www/web1` as the `root` for `/` (rather than `web1.example.ddns.net`), since that is what you initially specified in your question. In any case, to be clear, `root` needs to match whatever directory structure you have on your physical file system. That is, it doesn't have to mirror your `server_name`, unless you have actually made directories (or similar) called ex. `example.ddns.net` and `web1.example.ddns.net`.
- The first server block still uses `/var/www/example.ddns.net`, so make certain that is the correct path to wherever you are storing your files for `example.ddns.net`.
- Broadly, after making changes to your server, it is generally a wise step to clear your browser cache so that your browser isn't handing you back old data.